# Passing command-line arguments to mutliple java threads

Tags: java, multithreading, parameter-passing

I'm trying to create multiple threads in a java program and have them perform arithmetic operations on integers passed as command-line arguments. Obviously neither of the thread classes I'm trying to pass to are in the main method so how can I still access a variable like args[0] from these classes?

```
public class Mythread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new multiplication();
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        Runnable r2 = new summation();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
        t.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}

class summation implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        System.out.print(args[0]);
    }
}

class multiplication implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        System.out.print(args[1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should pass in the necessary information in the constructor

```
class Summation implements Runnable {

    private final String info;

    public Summation(String info) {
      this.info = info;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        System.out.print(info);
    }
}
```

Then you can pass in the args values to your threads in main so that you have them in your runnables / threads

public class Mythread {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable r = new multiplication(args[1]);
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    Runnable r2 = new summation(args[0]);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
    t.start();
    t2.start();
}
```

}